# loop inside multiple-level paths and rename

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Assuming I have a file named `list.txt` contains **paths** to files inside a directory;

And the paths pattern like this:

```
./path/to/file.txt
./path/to/another/file.txt
... etc
```

I want to loop inside `list.txt` file to get the paths of the files and change its encoding using `iconv`;

I was doing that if everything was in the same directory, using:

```
for i in `cat list.txt` ; do iconv -f windows-1256 -t utf8 $i > new_$i; done
```

But **the problem** I'm facing now is, since it's muli-level paths, naming the output of `iconv` prints the `new_$i` **in the start of** the path - I guess - and that gives me errors:

```
No such file or directory
```

So, how can I get the outpot of `iconv` to be like:

```
./path/to/new_file.txt
./path/to/another/new_file.txt
... etc
```

Comment: And pray, what is a *bath*, in computer speak?

Comment: sorry, I meant "Paths", it was a typo!

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this, if you're using `bash` as your shell:

```
while read name
do dir="${name%/*}" file="${name##*/}"
iconv -f windows-1256 -t utf8 "$dir/$file" -o "$dir/new_$file"
done  < list.txt
```

The line which assigns `dir` and `file` uses constructs documented in the `Parameter expansion` part of the `EXPANSION` section of the `bash` man page. The quote marks around the constructs are intended to handle white space in file names.

If you want to test something like this before using it, you can prepend `echo` to the command of interest (`iconv` in this example) to make sure the command is what you intend it to be.